# MSACESS: Populating a new record with data from a pulldown bounded column

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, key, ms-access-2010

I was able to get my pulldown combo-box (**cmb_users**) to pull up records in a sub-form (**contact_cards**).

Now I want users to be able to add additional records in the sub-form but with the ID text box (**txt_sc_owner_id**)prepopulated with the **sc_owner_id** of the combo-box to tie the records together and keep the data relevant.

What is a clean way to auto populate a new record text box with the data from the pull-down. The target field in the sub-form is **txt_sc_owner_id**. I figure, the sloppy code would look something like this.

[Forms]![contact_cards]![txt_sc_owner_id] = [Forms]![user_forms]!cmb_users.column(0)

The challenge is when to instantiate this when the user starts populating a new record in the sub-form

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `DefaultValue` of the textbox when updating the combobox:

```vb
Private Sub YourCombobox_AfterUpdate()

    Me!NameOfTheSubformControl.Form!sc_owr_id.DefaultValue = """" & Me!YourCombobox.Value & """"

End Sub
```

Comment: I like this idea, many thanks! but I have a mapping issue. I'll post a separate post for this.